# Compiling a shared library with Qt on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I am new to both Qt and Linux C++ development (although I have many years C and C++ development experience on Windows).

I have some legacy C projects (source files and headers - [not using Qt]) that I want to compile into shared libs on Linux.

I am proposing to store my projects under the following structure:

```
/home/username/Projects/project_name
/home/username/Projects/project_name/src
/home/username/Projects/project_name/build
```

Can anyone tell me how to do the following (using Qt to simplify the build process)

1. Create different build configurations (debug, release etc)
2. Build a configuration to create the appropriate shared library

As an aside, I have only recently installed Ubuntu 9.10 and the only C/C++ development tool I have installed (using SPM) in Qt - so I dont know if I need to install some other GNU C++ tools.

BTW I have already checked and have gcc (v4.4.1) available on my machine. I do not appear to have g++ though - I do not know whether this is significant or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Ubuntu system doesn't come with build tool chain by default. Instead it has a meta package that you will need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

This will install, among other the g++ compiler, although I am not sure about the Qt headers an such. For them you will need the qt4-dev package (I assume you wish to work with qt4 rather then qt3).

As for the bould structure, you will want to consult the [qmake manual](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qmake-manual.html), or you might want to consider using [CMake](http://cmake.org/) (`apt-get install cmake`) instead. CMake allow for out of build sources, as you require, and personally, I can't recommend it enough.

Comment: Thanks Chen Levy, I have installed both the build-essential and CMake packages (using SPM). I am reading the qmake manual now - looks like most of the answers are in there.

Comment: Managed to build succesfully using qmake. I'd like to accept your answer, but I havent figured out how to do that yet .. ;)

Comment: The stack overflow people, like to think the site have a grate UI. I guess if you have problem figuring it out, it needs some more work :). Anyhow, on question you asked, you should have a check-mark beside each question, you can toggle it on and off buy clicking it.